# combine several DbGeography polygons

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I am looking for ways to combine several polygons to reduce the number of points. Would this be the way forward:

```
var pol1 = DbGeography.PolygonFromText("POLYGON ((-2.91790532309701 53.3657440952224, -2.91790532309701 53.3567508791632, -2.90283703655041 53.3567508791632, -2.9028338560513 53.3657440952224, -2.91790532309701 53.3657440952224))", 4326);
var pol2 = DbGeography.PolygonFromText("POLYGON ((-2.90283703655041 53.3657440952224, -2.90283703655041 53.3567508791632, -2.88776875000381 53.3567508791632, -2.88776556950469 53.3657440952224, -2.90283703655041 53.3657440952224))", 4326);
var pol3 = DbGeography.PolygonFromText("POLYGON ((-2.91641048851245 53.3747373112816, -2.91641048851245 53.3657440952224, -2.90133902146673 53.3657440952224, -2.90133583925323 53.3747373112816, -2.91641048851245 53.3747373112816))", 4326);

var combined = (pol1.Union(pol2)).Union(pol3);
```

Basically, if the polygons touch each other, I want them to be combined. Disjoint polygons should remain disjoint.

At the moment I am not sure whether Union achieves the same as the TSQL function STUnion().

PS: I just run STUnion in TSQL and noticed that it also does not produce the intended results (i.e. the union contains points within the combined polygon).

Comment: There is a UnionAggregate function that is supposed to remove internal boundaries from the resulting unioned polygons if possible (much as Union is supposed to), but in testing it doesn't appear to be doing so.

Comment: I think this does not work with dbgeography either ...

Comment: I can confirm that union produces *something* - just not what you'd call a union. Trying to achieve exactly what setzkorn is after - and getting the same result. Just using the libraries and calling them from C#, not actually doing this in SQL Server.

Comment: I've spent the last hour trying to figure out GeographyUnionAggregate (in c# land) to no avail. The documentation is poor and I haven't seen a single example of usage beyond the book in front of me, and nothing in C#.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the result that I am seeing.

Here's a query:

```
declare @pol1 Geography, @pol2 Geography

set @pol1 = Geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON ((-2.91790532309701 53.3657440952224, -2.91790532309701 53.3567508791632, -2.90283703655041 53.3567508791632, -2.9028338560513 53.3657440952224, -2.91790532309701 53.3657440952224))', 4326);
set @pol2 = Geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON ((-2.90283703655041 53.3657440952224, -2.90283703655041 53.3567508791632, -2.88776875000381 53.3567508791632, -2.88776556950469 53.3657440952224, -2.90283703655041 53.3657440952224))', 4326);

select @pol1.STUnion(@pol2)
```

Here's the result:

[image]

If you add the @pol3 from your question, you might see a seam form. Try running the query with Geometry instead of Geography, and the seam will disappear. I suspect that's the buldge of the earth pushing it out, so you might need more points to 'stitch it together' if using Geography.

(I'm actually trying to get it not to join, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755560/combine-union-and-simplify-reduce-dbgeometry-records-for-geojson).)